# Get JSON data by webrequest vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I try to get json string data from a server. By clicking on a DIV block with a link like this(https://sub.domen.som/text/text/date).
And when I look in network->xhr data I can se a another link to .json-file like this(https://api.domen.com/text/text/date/text/date/text(look image))  my code looks

```
        Do Until addWB.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
    Sleep(3000)
    Dim newUrl As String = addWB.Url.AbsoluteUri
    Dim webReg As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(newUrl)
    webReg.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
    webReg.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    webReg.Accept = "application/json"
    Dim response As WebResponse = webReg.GetResponse()
    Using dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()  
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()  
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
    End Using
```

[image: network->xhr]

Only what I get is HTML code without data from json file.
What I need is get the right url to json file by webbrowser control or webrequest OR OR OR. Or get the json string

Hi

Now a change code and I had not all header in my first request. If I look into developer tool iexplore.
[image]

my code

```
 Dim webReg As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(newUrl)
        webReg.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
        webReg.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate")
        webReg.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-GB, en; q=0.8, sv-SE; q=0.5, sv; q=0.3")
        webReg.ContentType = "text/plain"
        webReg.KeepAlive = True
        webReg.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
        webReg.Referer = "servername"
        webReg.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer
    webReg.CookieContainer.SetCookies(New Uri(newUrl), addWB.Document.Cookie)
        webReg.Host = "api.servername"
        webReg.Headers.Add("Origin: servername")
        webReg.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
    webReg.Headers.Add("X-HttpWatch-RID: 1234-11834")

    Dim response As WebResponse = webReg.GetResponse()

    response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-credentials: true")
    response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
    response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-origin: servername")
    response.Headers.Add("access-control-expose-headers: X-Casper, Content-Length, X-Tenant, X-RC-Payload, X-RC-Messageid")
    response.Headers.Add("access-control-max-age: 1800")
    response.Headers.Add("content-encoding: gzip")
    response.Headers.Add("ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    response.Headers.Add("date: Fri, 04 Oct 2019 07:27:43 GMT")
    response.Headers.Add("server: nginx")
    response.Headers.Add("strict-transport-security: max-age=300; includeSubDomains;")
    response.Headers.Add("transfer-encoding: chunked")
    response.Headers.Add("x-server: prod-jupiter-lb-jupiter-21")
        Using dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
        End Using
```

all header both for request and respons are added. Now I get a response string like this
[image]

About few request: It's 4 request if I click on this DIV block. The first is of content type json and initiator type XMLHttpRequest, next to google.com and of content type image, next to same server as the first request and of content type img and last is of content type JS javascript. Have I to create a request to this with JS before Response or after response?

Comment: This is not answerable without more information. We can't tell you what path this particular server that we don't know about is serving JSON from. It's possible that the page you are visiting is serving a redirect which your browser follows but WebRequest doesn't - in which case check to see whether the result you get from requesting the page is a 3xx.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest in vb.net is httpRequest?

Comment: @Tom W Yes it is 3 request. Have I to do free request now or?

Comment: sorry, I can't understand what you're asking. If the URL you request is serving you a response with a 3xx range status code, that is a redirect, which means it's asking you to visit another URL to get the thing you came for. The response body will have the real URL in it, so you will have to write code to make a new request to that URL, because WebRequest won't automatically do that for you like your browser does.

Comment: @TomW `AllowAutoRedirect` is [true by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect?view=netframework-4.8#property-value).

Comment: @GSerg I stand corrected. So this probably isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get all Response Headers:

`MsgBox(WebRequest.GetResponse.Headers().ToString)`